# Installing discordjs/opus over normal discord.js has an error

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install

Recently, I asked a question on whether I could install discordjs/opus on top of an already installed discordjs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65973582/music-functionality-without-the-correct-package-discord-js/65985610#65985610). I was told it would probably not have any issues, however this is not the case. This is the error it sent upon installing:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\discordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json.3640863801
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\discordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\discordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json.3640863801' -> 'C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\beansdiscordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\discordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json.3640863801' -> 'C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\beansdiscordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\discordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json.3640863801' -> 'C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\beansdiscordbot\node_modules\ws\package.json'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\discordbot\\node_modules\\ws\\package.json.3640863801',
npm ERR!     dest: 'C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\discordbot\\node_modules\\ws\\package.json'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\discordbot\\node_modules\\ws\\package.json.3640863801',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\discordbot\\node_modules\\ws\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'discordbot'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

(I replaced my real name with 'MYNAME')

Any help will be appreciated on how I get around this.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the Powershell using right click > Run as administrator. And retry. It will work, it is a simple permissions problem.

Comment: Just tried this and ran npm install discord.js @discordjs/opus, it then says this error:
`Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'`
And I had to rollback as it crashed. Can you offer any suggestions/help on how to fix this :)?

Comment: Use npm install discord.js